# MongoDB feature or query to compare two documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does MongoDB have a feature or query to compare two documents and get property having different values?

Below is the actual scenario which I am trying to implement.

Sample Document 1 (Version1)

```
{
  "firstName": "Rack's",
  "lastName": "Jackon",
  "gender": "man",
  "age": 24,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "126",
    "city": "San Jone",
    "state": "CA",
    "postalCode": "394221"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "7383627627"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sample Document 2 (Version 2)

```
{
  "firstName": "Rack's",
  "lastName": "Mathew",
  "gender": "man",
  "age": 28,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "126",
    "city": "San Jone",
    "state": "CA",
    "postalCode": "394221"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "Work",
      "number": "7383627888"
    }
  ]
}
```

In above sample JSON there are only 4 properties which are different so want to get either properties with different values/ only property name will also work.

Expected Output

| Property Name | Document 1 | Document 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lastName | Jackson | Mathew |
| age | 24 | 28 |
| phoneNumbers.type | home | Work |
| phoneNumbers.number | 7383627627 | 7383627888 |

So do we have any specific query or in built feature which can be helpful.

One way is to get records from MongoDB and compare it with integrating technology (.NET in my case) but want to do it on MongoDB end only.

Any suggestion is helpful, thanks in advance.

Able to get mentioned expected output by retrieving records and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is generic way in MongoDB to achieve exactly what you want, as comparison might be tricky if the same field has different types(e.g. array vs object)

Nevertheless, you may partially achieve the diff by`$objectToArray` the 2 documents into array of kv-tuples and perform a `$setDifference` to find out the diff.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": "uniqueId",
      "ver": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      let: {
        oldVer: "$ver"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "$ver",
                "$$oldVer"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            ver: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "newVersion"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$newVersion"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      old: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      },
      new: {
        "$objectToArray": "$newVersion"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      diff: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$setDifference": [
              "$old",
              "$new"
            ]
          },
          "as": "diffEntry",
          "cond": {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$diffEntry.k",
                [
                  "newVersion",
                  "ver",
                  "_id"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jVE-T4Cce6-)

---

On the other hand, your scenario suggests that you want to capture change between different versions of the same document. You may find [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) useful in that case.